# Spotify docker maven build multiple images

Tags: java, maven, docker, spotify

I am using spotify's Docker maven plugin and want in to build two different images, one is a database (MariaDB) and the other is a Java EE image (Glassfish).

I have managed to get Maven to build the images OK when ran seperately however when I try and run both in the same POM file it will only create the first image.

I have tried putting two configuration sections within the single plugin and get the error below:

> [ERROR]     Non-parseable POM C:\Users\607819425\Documents\InteliJProjects\feature_docker\pom.xml: Duplicated tag: 'configuration' (position:START_TAG seen ...\r\n                ... @300:32)  @line 300, column 32 -> [Help 2]

Pom file with 2 configuration tags in one plugin

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
            <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.4.11</version>
            <configuration>
                <imageName>glassfish</imageName>
                <dockerDirectory>glassfish</dockerDirectory>
                <baseImage>java</baseImage>
                <entryPoint>["java", "-jar", "/${project.build.finalName}.jar"]</entryPoint>
                <!-- copy the service's jar file from target into the root directory of the image -->
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <targetPath>/</targetPath>
                        <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                        <include>${project.build.finalName}.jar</include>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
            <configuration>
                <imageName>mariadb</imageName>
                <dockerDirectory>mariadb</dockerDirectory>
                <baseImage>java</baseImage>
                <entryPoint>["java", "-jar", "/${project.build.finalName}.jar"]</entryPoint>
                <!-- copy the service's jar file from target into the root directory of the image -->
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <targetPath>/</targetPath>
                        <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                        <include>${project.build.finalName}.jar</include>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

And Also with two seperate plugins it only every builds the first image.

Two Plugin POM:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
            <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.4.11</version>
            <configuration>
                <imageName>glassfish</imageName>
                <dockerDirectory>glassfish</dockerDirectory>
                <baseImage>java</baseImage>
                <entryPoint>["java", "-jar", "/${project.build.finalName}.jar"]</entryPoint>
                <!-- copy the service's jar file from target into the root directory of the image -->
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <targetPath>/</targetPath>
                        <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                        <include>${project.build.finalName}.jar</include>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
            <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.4.11</version>
            <configuration>
                <imageName>mariadb</imageName>
                <dockerDirectory>mariadb</dockerDirectory>
                <baseImage>java</baseImage>
                <entryPoint>["java", "-jar", "/${project.build.finalName}.jar"]</entryPoint>
                <!-- copy the service's jar file from target into the root directory of the image -->
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <targetPath>/</targetPath>
                        <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                        <include>${project.build.finalName}.jar</include>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Any info you could give would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Switched to Fabric8.io's version of the plugin in the end as multiple images are supported.

[Fabric 8 Docker Maven Plugin](https://dmp.fabric8.io/)